# Error: No UserDetails model is Created

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to reduce the image size before upload. I'm using default `User` model given by django & linking it to another model just to add few more things to the user profile.

This is how models.py looks like,

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True)
    ... 

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    img = Image.open(self.profile)
    resize = img.resize((240, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    new_image = BytesIO()
    resize.save(new_image, format=img.format)
    temp_name = self.profile.name
    self.profile.save(temp_name, content=ContentFile(new_image.getvalue()), save=False)
    super(UserDetails, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Problem is that when I'm signing up with fields `username`, `first_name` & `password`, it's not creating a `UserDetails` model along with that user. So, if I try to visit any user's profile it gives an error, `no UserDetails model is present`.

If I remove the image compression code from the model & sign up again everything starts working perfectly fine.

How can we fix that? Thank You . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super must be first line after you override save()

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserDetails, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.profile:
        img = Image.open(self.profile)
        resize = img.resize((240, 240), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        new_image = BytesIO()
        resize.save(new_image, format=img.format)
        temp_name = self.profile.name
        self.profile.save(temp_name, content=ContentFile(new_image.getvalue()), save=False)
```

Comment: Sir, now it's raising an error, `The 'profile' attribute has no file associated with it.`

Comment: while uploading picture ?

Comment: No Sir, while signing up!

Comment: are you attaching any picture during signup?

Comment: I added, `if self.profile:` condition just after the super() & was able to sign up, but now it's not resizing the images.

Comment: No, sir. I'm adding picture after user is created

Comment: updated my answer accordingly, need to put the code after super() inside if condition. that will only run when there is profile pic is uploaded. try now

Comment: Sir, now I can sign up properly, but now it's not resizing the images whenever I upload them, it's ignoring the resizing code & uploading them just as they are. Why so?

Comment: Problem solved, I added the super() after `if` condition. Now it's working fine. Thank You sir it helped me a lot :)

Comment: if so, then try signing up again, Super() should be called before you override save() with any code

Comment: glad, that helped. :)